# Single cell string to list to multiple rows

Tags: pandas

I have a pandas data frame,

[image: Data Frame (df)]

Currently the list column is a string, I want to delimit this by spaces and replicate rows for each primary key would be associated with each item in the list. Can you please advise me on how I can achieve this?

## Edit:

I need to copy down the value column after splitting and stacking the list column

Comment: Thank you all for the prompt response I will attempt these solutions and verify

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My version:

```
df['List'].str.split().explode()
```

produces

```
0    a
0    b
0    c
1    d
1    e
1    f
```

With regards to the **Edit** of the question,  the following tweak will give you want you need I think:

```
df['List'] = df['List'].str.split()
df.explode('List')
```

Answer (score 2):

If your data frame is `df` you can do:

`df.List.str.split(' ').apply(pd.Series).stack()`

and you will get

```
Primary Key   
0            0    a
             1    b
             2    c
1            0    d
             1    e
             2    f
dtype: object
```

You are splitting the variable List on spaces, turning the resulting list into a series, and then stacking it to turn it into long format, indexed on the primary key, along with a sequence for each item obtained from the split.

Comment: Instead of a sequence I have other columns that I need to be copied down. For example another column that is associated with the primary key. Can I export to excel the pandas series without creating data frame?

Comment: Could you show your actual data structure? But you could just merge the stacked frame with the original frame.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution.

```
df = df.assign(**{'list':df['list'].str.split()}).explode('list')
df['cc'] = df.groupby(level=0)['list'].cumcount()
df.set_index(['cc'],append=True)
```